# How to load an external html into an html using emberjs

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

My current HTML page has run into 1000 lines of code. I wanted to make it more manageable.

So the kind of solution I'm looking for is -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-load-template="detail.html">
```

And the code should be able to load `detail.html` from an external source.

How do I do it?

Comment: Are you converting an existing app to ember? Or do you have a big template for some view, and want to divide.

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to use some kind of build tool like **grunt** that will compile **handlebars** files to javascript and attach them to you code.

Here is a project that you may find useful: https://github.com/yaymukund/grunt-ember-handlebars